# Uniqueness of integral curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a vector field $X$ on a smooth manifold $M$ and a point $p \in M$, we know that there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of p, an $\epsilon >0$ and a unique local flow $F : U \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ of $X$, i.e. each $\gamma_y:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ defined by $\gamma_y (t)= F(y,t)$ is an integral curve of $X$ with $\gamma_y(0)=y$.

I want to prove the following.

> Given an integral curve $\gamma : (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to M$ of $X$ with $\gamma(0) = p$, this is the only integral curve of $X$ that passes through $p$.

If we were given a family of integral curves passing through every point in a neighborhood of $p$, this would have been obvious from the uniqueness theorem. But how do I conclude the uniqueness when only one integral curve is given?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the theorem of existence and uniqueness of ODE with the theorem of maximal solution. I think that would suffice.

Comment: The uniqueness depends on the regularity of the vector fiel $X$. For instance if it is only continuous, the is no reason that the curve is unique. let $X=\sqrt x \partial _x + \partial _y$ if $x>0$, $X=\partial _y$ if not. Then $x(t)= t^2/2, y(t)=t $ and $x(t)=0, y(t)=t$ are two integral curves with the same initial data $x(0)=y(0)=0$